# Cannot acces 'LinkedHashTreeMap' : it's a public /*package*/ com.squareup.moshi

Tags: android, kotlin, moshi

In my android app, I use a Kotlin with minSdkVersion 26 targetSdkVersion 28. In the build.gradle, I add the following lines :

> ```
> implementation 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:1.9.2'
> implementation 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi:1.9.2'
> ```

But, when I want to use 'LinkedHashTreeMap', It does not accept it and the following error appear :

> Cannot acces 'LinkedHashTreeMap' : it's a public /*package*/
>   com.squareup.moshi

I would like to know what's the problem and How can I correct it ?

Comment: Need to see the code where this error is originating from. But, it looks like LinkedHashTreeMap is a package and not a class and you are probably trying to use it as a class in your code somewhere. Do you know the difference between a package and a class?

Comment: Could you please see the following lien
https://github.com/square/moshi/blob/master/moshi/src/main/java/com/squareup/moshi/LinkedHashTreeMap.java

Comment: Can you please post the code?

Comment: Here's where I use the linkedhashtreemap
        val prodItem = products[position] as LinkedHashTreeMap<*,*>
and here's the following error :
    java.lang.ClassCastException: com.squareup.moshi.LinkedHashTreeMap cannot be cast to java.util.LinkedHashMap

Answer (score 1):

That class is an implementation detail of Moshi. You should use `LinkedHashMap` in your own code.

Comment: I get the following error java.lang.ClassCastException: com.squareup.moshi.LinkedHashTreeMap cannot be cast to java.util.LinkedHashMap

Comment: Try Map instead?

Comment: Casting it to Map worked in my case, thanks @JesseWilson